# populate values in Form control from nested Form Array from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

[FormArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOjxf.png)The formObj has array of componentDetails Object which in turn has a nested array of component array.

```
   export class FormViewComponent implements OnInit {

    public callbackForm: FormGroup;

    formObj = {
        "componentDetails": [{
            "component": [{
                "value": "Choice 1"
            }, {
                "value": "Choice 2"
            }],
            "cpv": "",
            "label": "Description of Problem",
            "type": "radio",
            "mandatory": true
        }]
    };

    loadObservableForm() {
        this.formService.getData(this.id)
            .subscribe(
                (formObj) => {
                    this.formObj = formObj;
                    this.callbackForm = this._formBuild.group({
                        componentDetails: this._formBuild.array([])
                    });
                    this.addComponentDetails();
                },
                (err) => console.error(err),
                () => console.log('observable complete')
            );

    }

    addComponentDetails() {
        const control = <FormArray> this.callbackForm.controls.componentDetails;
        this.formObj.componentDetails.forEach(x => {
            control.push(this.addControl(x));
        });
    }

    addControl(x) {
        const group = this._formBuild.group({
            label: x.label,
            cpv: x.cpv,
            type: x.type,
            mandatory: x.mandatory,
            component: this._formBuild.array([this.addOptions(x)])
        });
        return group;
    }

    addOptions(z) {
        const control = < FormArray > z.component;
        z.component.forEach(y => {
            control.push(this.addOptionRow(y.value));
        });
    }

    addOptionRow(value) {
        return this._formBuild.group({
            value: value
        });
    }
}
```

Template HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="callbackForm">
    <div>
        <div formArrayName="componentDetails">
            <div *ngFor="let question of callbackForm.controls.componentDetails.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 panel-group panel-group--compressed">
                    <div class="panel panel--default">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="row" *ngIf="question.controls.type.value === 'radio'">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p>{{ question.controls.label.value }}</p>
                                    <div formArrayName="component">
                                        <div *ngFor="let answer of question.controls.component.controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
                                        <label class="radio radio--alt radio--stacked">
                                        <input type="radio" name="radio-stacked">
                                        <span class="radio__input"></span>
                                        <span class="radio__label">{{ answer.value }}</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Problem:

In the component template HTML, I cannot get the value for {{ answer.value }}. I tried with answer.controls.value.value and answer.controls.value. And nothing is working. question.controls.component.controls returns [Object Object]

Comment: Here is a good article about "Nested model-driven forms": https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2  There are some plunkr so you'll be able to play with it and test a solution for your need.

Comment: Have you tried using `return group` instead of `question.push(group);` in `addOption` method?

Comment: Sorry, return group did not work :(

Comment: Is this code at all working? When I try it, the formarray is `null`?

Comment: I get the formObj as a JSON by calling an API.  console.log(controls) inside addComponentDetails returns FormArray. I have added the screenshot of FormArray in the question

Comment: @DavidJeyathilak I understand that, but for me the `callbackForm.controls.componentDetails` is always null, even though there is values in `formObj`. When modifying your methods a bit I do get the values populated. Weird :P That is why I asked if it works for you.

Comment: I am not able to get the component formObj JSON values to be created as Form Control in callbackForm :( I do not know how to do that in here `        z.component.forEach(y => {
            control.push(this.addOptionRow(y.value));
        });` instead of z.component, I do not know how to do this.formObj.componentDetails[of something].component.forEach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have trouble when calling `addOptions` inside the form array:

```
component: this._formBuild.array([this.addOptions(x)])
```

Place that below instead, so this will work. I omitted `addOptions` and `addOptionRow` from your code and instead applied the logic in `addControl`:

```ts
addControl(x) {
  const group = this._formBuild.group({
    label: x.label,
    cpv: x.cpv,
    type: x.type,
    mandatory: x.mandatory,
    component: this._formBuild.array([])
  });
  const ctrl = group.controls.component as FormArray;
  x.component.forEach(y => {
    ctrl.push(this._formBuild.group({
      value: y.value
    }))
  })
  return group;
}
```

and your template is otherwise correct, but to show the label do:

```ts
{{ answer.value.value }}
```

instead of

```ts
{{ answer.value }}
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxiilx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I can't get the selectedValue (Choice 1 or Choice 2) of the radio in the <pre>{{callbackForm.value | json }}</pre> for sending the selectedValue on Form Submission

Comment: I forked your stackblitz to add selectedValue with the formObj to capture the radio selection. Not sure if it's right approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518664/formcontrolname-for-radio-group-for-form-submission

Comment: Hi @AJT_82, could you please let me know how to get the selected Value on Form Submission? Thank you!