# Angular Form Array of object is not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

```
// setup the form
const formGroup = {};
for (const prop of Object.keys(this.dataObject)) {
  try {
    const cpv = this.dataObject[prop].cpv;
    const value = this.dataObject[prop].value;
    formGroup['componentDetails'] = new FormArray([
      new FormControl({'cpv': cpv, 'value': value})
    ]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Exception in Form setup - ' + e);
  }
}
```

I have the above code to set-up form control and form array for my form. The resulting JSON that is generated does not add value property :(

What I get:

`"componentDetails": [
    {
      "cpv": "CPV_1"
    }
  ]`

What I need

`"componentDetails": [
    {
      "cpv": "CPV_1",
      "value": "test value"
    }
  ]`

I do not see any errors. Was wondering if you anyone faced the same issue and how they solved it?

Comment: Well you are just creating one formcontrol, when you obviously need two. That's at least a problem on first glance :)

Comment: cpv and value have to go together as a pair when we submit the form...[{ 'cpv' : 'cpv1', 'value': 'test1'}, {'cpv': 'cpv2', 'value': 'test2'}]

Comment: @DavidJeyathilak Then you could create them as an object; check my edit

Comment: @AJT_82 I am trying this in another way at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781055/populate-values-in-form-control-from-nested-form-array-from-json-data

Answer (score 1):

As @AJT_82 suggested `value` would have to be another `FormControl`:

```
formGroup['componentDetails'] = new FormArray([
  new FormControl({'cpv': cpv}),
  new FormControl({''value': value})
]);
```

**EDIT**: If they need to go as a pair:

```
const cpv = this.dataObject[prop].cpv;
const value = this.dataObject[prop].value;
let pair: any = { 'cpv': cpv, 'value': value };

formGroup['componentDetails'] = new FormArray([
    new FormControl(pair)
]);
```

See: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray